Data flow sink collation error when trying to direct output into a table in Dedicated SQL pool
Im trying to load data from 2 csv files located in storage account container, join them, select columns and output the result to a table in a DedicatedSQLPool, but im getting the following error:
No column collation was specified in external table definition and the collation of current database 'Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8' is not supported for external tables of type 'HADOOP'. Please specify a supported collation in the column definition.

{
  "message": "Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'OneSumXRegOut': 105105;No column collation was specified in external table definition and the collation of current database 'Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8' is not supported for external tables of type 'HADOOP'. Please specify a supported collation in the column definition.. Details:shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 105105;No column collation was specified in external table definition and the collation of current database 'Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8' is not supported for external tables of type 'HADOOP'. Please specify a supported collation in the column definition.\n\tat shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:265)\n\tat shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1673)\n\tat shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:907)\n\tat shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:802)\n\tat shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7627)\n\tat shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3912)\n\tat shaded.msda",
  "failureType": "UserError",
  "target": "load 1009 and 6000",
  "errorCode": "DFExecutorUserError"
}

What am I doing wrong?
Here is the data flow image:
data flow
Sink configuration images:
sink general
sink mapping
I've tried changing all table columns type to varchar(4000), but with no luck.
